# OpenCV video write to file works but video is blank

Tags: python, opencv, conv-neural-network, codec

I am using opencv for some neural style transfer trick, but I am having trouble saving the video to file. The file is created, but it is only 6 kb large.

```
from imutils.video import VideoStream
from imutils import paths
import itertools
import argparse
import imutils
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-m", "--models", required=True,
    help="path to directory containing neural style transfer models")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())


modelPaths = paths.list_files(args["models"], validExts=(".t7",))
modelPaths = sorted(list(modelPaths))


models = list(zip(range(0, len(modelPaths)), (modelPaths)))

modelIter = itertools.cycle(models)
(modelID, modelPath) = next(modelIter)


print("[INFO] loading style transfer model...")
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTorch(modelPath)


print("[INFO] starting video stream...")
vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()
time.sleep(2.0)
print("[INFO] {}. {}".format(modelID + 1, modelPath))



out = cv2.VideoWriter('output2.avi', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID'), 5, (451, 600))
while True:

    frame = vs.read()




    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=600)
    orig = frame.copy()
    (h, w) = frame.shape[:2]


    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1.0, (w, h),
        (103.939, 116.779, 123.680), swapRB=False, crop=False)
    net.setInput(blob)
    output = net.forward()


    output = output.reshape((3, output.shape[2], output.shape[3]))
    output[0] += 103.939
    output[1] += 116.779
    output[2] += 123.680
    output /= 255.0
    output = output.transpose(1, 2, 0)

    out.write(np.uint8(output))

    cv2.imshow("Input", frame)
    cv2.imshow("Output", output)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    if key == ord("n"):

        (modelID, modelPath) = next(modelIter)
        print("[INFO] {}. {}".format(modelID + 1, modelPath))
        net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTorch(modelPath)
        print(frame.shape)

    elif key == ord("q"):
        break


cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vs.stop()
```

The main stuff are happening at:

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output2.avi', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID'), 5, (450, 600))
output = net.forward() # which computes the neural styled output image
```

and to save output/frame to file, I did:

```
out.write(np.uint8(output))
```

Any ideas on why isn't my code working? I have tried many codec and file type combinations, and I don't believe the problem is there. Do you guys think it might be the dimension? (I have 450, 600 right now because I printed output.shape and it returned 450,600,3 so I think 450 x 600 sounds right).

Comment: If you write `np.uint8(output)` to the video, then you should `imshow` the same thing. I see `output /= 255.0`, so my guess is that output is a floating point array with values in range [0.0, 1.0]. Casting that to `uint8` will reduce it to just 0s and 1s. However, `imshow` (as per documentation) will convert and scale floating point images back to 0-255 range.

Comment: @DanMašek is correct. You can read more about what he described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37027314/4228275).

Comment: make sure your application has access to the opencv_ffmpeg dll (or shared lib?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Dan Mašek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3962537/dan-ma%c5%a1ek)'s comment is probably correct. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37027314/4228275). For completeness, you could fix it by:

1. Changing `out.write(np.uint8(output))` to `out.write(np.uint8(output * 255))`

**or**

2. Comment `output /= 255.0` and change `cv2.imshow("Output", output)` to `cv2.imshow("Output", output / 255.)`

You should choose the solution based on whether you want `output` to be on the (1) `[0., 1.]` or (2) `[0, 255]` range.

Comment: Since `output` is only used to write either a video or show an image, I'd say the scaling is absolutely useless in the code shown. As such, I'd propose approach #3 -- ditch the `output /= 255.0` and replace it with `output = np.uint8(output)`. Then you can pass the **same** image to both `write` and `imshow` (I assume the reason for displaying it as well as writing is to be able to see exactly what it is you write). Anyway, +1 to you for writing an answer even though the OP couldn't be bothered to respond...

Comment: so sorry, I didn't see this response. I will try it out first thing tomorrow morning.